# How to find a specific key value from Json object stored in a column of Oracle table

Tags: oracle11g

in my Oracle db, i have a table namely, "remittanceHistories" which has a column called, "changelog" in which both request object sent and response object received are stored like this:

```
{
    "req": {
        "args": {

            "chargingMode": "",
            "destinationUri": "",
            "cbsType": "",
            "isBankDeposit": ""
        },
        "method": ""
    },
    "res": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "",
        "transactionId": "18070685476",
        "chTransactionId": "10111715789"
    }
}
```

I want a query that finds "chTransactionId" only by skipping the rest.

Any help?

Comment: Which version of oracle you are using? It's already there in 12c. But if you are using 11g or lesser then there are some user defined packages which will help you to do so.

Comment: @Nilayshah, i'm using 11g as shown above but not getting what you mean, "some user defined packages " !

Comment: i once tried it with "SUBSTR " function but failed to get it done.